# Craft\Exception on saving entries having images

Tags: entry, image, saveentry, imagick

I have created a new entry in which user can also add images(already uploaded or new upload)

I can save entry successfully if I don't add any images to it. When I add any image and try to save the entry following error is displayed-

> Craft\Exception
>
> This file type is not allowed

Earlier different error was displayed which was related to **imagick**.
Since I have installed imagick and it's php extension, the error is replaced by this new error.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say you're trying to upload a file type that isn't allowed under that Asset fields "Restrict Allowed File Types?" section.